# Division by zero with cross entropy cost function

Tags: neural-networks

I am using a tanh as my activation function for my NN.  I also was using the cross entropy cost function previously when I had sigmoid neurons.  The sigmoid neurons can never make it to zero but a tanh can and when I train the NN I will get division by zero errors.  I switched back to the quadratic cost function but it converges slowly.  Is there a way to use the cross entropy cost with a tanh or is there something better I could use?

Comment: When exactly do you get divizion by zero errors?

Comment: When any of the outputs of the neural net are zero.

Comment: tanh returns values from -1 to 1. Cross-entropy assumes that values are from 0 to 1.  How do you use cross entropy with tanh?

Comment: Ok.  Is there a better cost function to use for tanh

Comment: Am I correct that your outputs of the neural net are from -1 to 1? (many of them are negative)?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: By cross-entropy, you mean the loss function p*log(q)+(1-p)*log(1-q), where p=true output (0 or 1), and q is the neural net's output?

Comment: Yes that is the function

Comment: So when q<0, which happens often, you try to calculate logarithm of negative number? Is it correct?

Comment: I think so.  I think it is mostly when a value gets saturated at one since I only have finite percision and when I compute the derivative of the cost there is an output -1 in the denominator

Comment: Finite precision is another issue which can be adressed separately. Is it true that in many cases you are trying to calculate the log of negative number?  This is not connected to the finite precision.

Comment: Well there are no logs when you take the derivative but I guess this would still not make sense

Comment: There are logs when you calculate the cross-entropy function.  Are these logs sometimes of negative parameter?

Comment: Or you mean that you never calculate the cross-entropy function explicity, but instead use its derivative?

Comment: That is what I mean.  I suppose it does not make sense to take the derivative where the function is undefined.  I think cross entropy will not work with tanh.  I will just need a different cost function.

Comment: I think you need sigmoid function.  Why is it bad that sigmoid neurons can never make it (output) to zero?

Comment: It's not bad. I just chose to use tanh.  I could probably just switch back.

Comment: Try sigmoid function, at least for the output neuron.  IMHO, it makes no sense to use tanh function with cross-entropy.

Answer (score 1):

It's common to use softmax as a final layer. It helps you to convert the output values to the probabilities. If you use softmax as an activation function for the final layer you can use any function you like for the previous layers.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make any sense: a cross entropy loss means that you are making some distributional assumption.

One typical distributional assumption is that the target values are Bernoulli and the predictive distributions are Bernoulli.  Therefore, the cross entropy is the expected surprisal.  This is logistic regression.  This is "logistic loss".

Another typical distributional assumption is normal with fixed variance.  Then the cross entropy loss is equivalent to linear regression in the same way.  This is the "quadratic loss".

Which distributional assumption corresponds to tanh?